# Problem to open office word document in word online

Tags: sharepoint-server, office, server, offline

I've implemented office online server on a VM machine. Also, I've installed SharePoint 2019 successfully on another VM and connect it to the office offline server. Office offline server turns out to work properly based on the bellow image:
[image: OfficeWebAppsFarm]

I connected SharePoint server to office farm and it also sounds work correctly based on the bellow image :

[image]

Both VM machines are connected to the Active directory (AD). The problem is that when I wanna open word, excel or any office apps via SharePoint it opens as a blank page and not open in the browser !!!. What exactly I need is to open office apps via web browser such as chrome or any other web browsers.

[image]

Comment: is SSL enabled ?

Comment: AIMEN BOULAHIA No it's not. Is it necessary ??